# Cassandra 2.0 - CQL3 schema changes not propagated through rest of cluster even after 30+ minutes

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax

I created a table in CQL 3.0 / Cassandra 1.2 a few months ago with a pretty simple table structure that included a couple of columns with CQL3 collections.

Today I rolled out an update to the schema for that table on our development C* cluster, which has since been upgraded to Cassandra 2.0 running CQL 3.1.

I ran the following command via `cqlsh` on one of the 4 nodes in our ring today:

`ALTER TABLE ExistingTable DROP OldColumn1;
ALTER TABLE ExistingTable DROP OldColumn1_; --used for DSE Search solr indexing; no longer needed
ALTER TABLE ExistingTable ADD NewColumn set<uuid>;`

However, after 30 minutes I was seeing some failing tests from our application and was pretty surprised to see that while the node I ran these changes on had the correct schema, none of these changes were ever propagated to its peers in the ring. I've been using Cassandra for a year and a half and have never seen this before.

How can I fix this and what caused the issue?

**Edit**
This might help explain what's going on. Got the following error when I tried to kick off a `nodetool repair`:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeCmd : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.  Program will exit.

Comment: In case anyone asks, the Cassandra servers themselves are running fine. Haven't had any issues with them until now AFAIK. It's also not an obvious JDK7 issue - at least not with Cassandra itself, given that DSE is running properly.

Comment: Yeah, but your node tool definition has a JDK7 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code was compiled for JDK 7, and you are running on JDK 6.

Comment: DSE 4.0.3 / Cassandra 2.0.7 runs fine on that machine, and it also has to target JDK7. IIRC, NodeTool gets updated along with the Cassandra / Solr / Hadoop bits. What would have gone wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are even invoking the Cassandra 2.0.7 nodetool?

Comment: So it looks like there's a definite JDK issue with Nodetool. Cassandra's pointing at JDK7, but the JAVA_HOME path variable is still pointing at JDK6. I'll fix that, but it doesn't explain the CQL schema issue.

Answer (score 2):

I followed Christopher's suggestion and fixed my JDK issue with nodetool / dse tool. Cassandra worked because looks for a symbolic link to the "java" command, which was correctly set to JRE 7 during the upgrade to Oracle JDK7, and uses that to run its jars. All of the command line tools except for `cqlsh`, however, all depend on the JAVA_HOME environment variable, which was incorrectly set to Java 6. That's why Cassandra 2.0 could run but nodetool could not.

After fixing that issue my schema replicated instantly to other nodes once I re-applied my schema changes to a different node.